# incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a function that generates random arrays:

```
  private static List<Integer> randomIntegerArray(int n) {
    int[] array = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i <  array.length; i++) {
      array[i] = (int)Math.random();
    }
    return array;
  }
```

I'm getting the following error:

> incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to java.util.List

I'm not sure what the issue is here.  This is an incredibly simple bit of code that I can't seem to get to work.

Comment: A `List` is not an array. If you want to return an int array, your return type needs to be `int[]`

Comment: @khelwood so how do in initialize/append a `List<Integer>`?

Comment: It's telling you the type cannot be converted automagically. You have to create the type you want to return.

Comment: Note: `(int)Math.random()` is always `0`

Comment: I could say that the error message itself contains an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're returning `List<Integer>`, but you're creating an `int[]`. They're completely different things! try this instead:

```
  private static List<Integer> randomIntegerArray(int n) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      list.add((int) Math.random()); // always returns 0
    }
    return list;
  }
```

Or if you definitely want to use an array, change the method's declaration:

```
private static int[] randomIntegerArray(int n)
```

And be aware that `Math.random()` returns a value between `0` and `1`, if you convert it to an `int` it'll *always* be `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You can have simpler code that actually produces random integers instead of zeros by directly using the `Random` class:

```
private static List<Integer> randomIntegerArray(int n) {
  return ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(n).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This may return any `Integer` value; you can specify a range with additional arguments to the [`ints()` method.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#ints-long-int-int-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Oscar's answer would be:

```
private static int[] randomIntegerArray(int n) {
    int[] array = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int)Math.random();
    }
    return array;
}
```

As others have said, a `List` of type `Integer` is not the same thing as an array of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this wouldn't be the best choice but also works, altough you'll get always a zero list of integers as Peter Lawrey says:

```
private static List<Integer> randomIntegerArray(int n) {
    Integer[] array = new Integer[n];

    for(int i = 0; i <  array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = Double.valueOf(Math.random()).intValue();
    }
    return Arrays.asList(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error tells you that arrays and list are not compatible, a quick search would have shown you ways to convert one to the other like Arrays.asList ().
Secondly Math.random returns a random number between 0.0 and 0.9 so you need to multiply by the number you want. 
You may need to go through a quick tutorial on Java first. 
All the best.